# Powershell move AD object

Tags: powershell, object, active-directory, move

i made this script to find all windows 10 machines which are not placed in the right OU, there is no action taken at this point - but i would like to move them once they had been found, we have over 30 country's and data centers so i would like to keep the OU string in the arrays, to keep the code to a minimal  - how would one perform a move in this script? i could use some pointers.

```
$Script:OUBase = "OU=Countries,OU=Global,DC=internal"
    Import-Module ActiveDirectory



    $CountryDataCenter = 
    @(
    [pscustomobject]@{Country="UK";DataCenter="CEN1"},
    [pscustomobject]@{Country="UK";DataCenter="CEN2"} 
    )


    Function GetWin10MachineAccounts($Country, $DataCenter){


    #Build OUstring
    $OUStringTarget = "*OU=Windows 10,OU=Computers,OU=" + $DataCenter + ",OU=" + $Country + "," + $Script:OUBase
    $OUStringSource = "OU=Computers,OU=" + $DataCenter + ",OU=" + $Country + "," + $Script:OUBase
    $countPC    = ($Win10Computeraccounts).count


    Write-Host "OU to search - " $OUStringSource -ForegroundColor Yellow


    $Win10ComputerAccounts = Get-ADComputer -SearchBase $OUStringSource -Filter {(enabled -eq "true") -and (OperatingSystem -like "*Windows 10*")} -properties * | where {$_.DistinguishedName -notlike "$OUStringTarget"} | select CN -expandproperty Name 


    Return $Win10Computeraccounts




    }



    ############### Main Script ##########################

    ##create empty array for use later
    $DataArray = @()

    ForEach ($Country in $CountryDataCenter)
    {
        $Win10Computeraccounts = GetWin10MachineAccounts $Country.Country $Country.DataCenter 
        $countPC    = $Win10Computeraccounts.count




        if(!$Win10Computeraccounts) {
         write-host "No Windows 10 Computers are found in the container" $Country.Country $Country.DataCenter
        }

        foreach ($Computer in $Win10Computeraccounts){     
            Write-Host $Computer -ForegroundColor Red
            #Store Data in foreach array
            $DataArray += (Get-ADComputer $Computer )
            Write-Host "$countPC" "Computers found in" $Country.Country $Country.DataCenter -ForegroundColor Green


        } 



    }



    $DataArray | Export-Csv "C:\log.csv"  -Force
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`Move-ADObject` cmdlet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617248.aspx):

```
foreach($Country in $CountryDataCenter)
{
    $OUStringTarget = "OU=Windows 10,OU=Computers,OU={0},OU={1},{2}" -f $Country.DataCenter,$Country.Country,$Script:OUBase
    $Win10Computeraccounts = GetWin10MachineAccounts $Country.Country $Country.DataCenter 

    foreach ($Computer in $Win10Computeraccounts){     
        Move-ADObject -Identity $Computer -TargetPath $OUStringTarget
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but i need string target to be dynamic for each location

Comment: It *is* dynamic, notice how the `$OUStringTarget` string is constructed - using the current `Country` and `DataCenter` values. Basically the same as in your `GetWin10MachineAccounts` function, just using the `-f` operator instead of concatenating the strings

Comment: Move-ADObject : Cannot find an object with identity: 'VPC02' under: 'OU=Countries,OU=Global,DC=internal'.
At line:75 char:9
+         Move-ADObject -Identity $Computer -TargetPath $OUStringTarget
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (VPC02:ADObject) [Move-ADObject], ADIdentityNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADIdentityNotFoundException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.MoveADObject

Comment: Remove the `| select CN -expandproperty Name` statement from the `GetWin10MachineAccounts` - no need to throw away everything but the name when you're going to use it later

Comment: Great, but everything is now moved to Cen2 even though that it was placed in Cen1

Comment: The script is as you posted it, but with my `foreach` loop inplace of yyour own in the "main script" part, and computers are now being moved from one data center to another? Sounds very unlikely. How exactly did you incorporate my answer?

Comment: Thanks got it working now, there was a duplicate move string earlier in the script :) Could you tell med more about this  - "OU=Windows 10,OU=Computers,OU={0},OU={1},{2}" Do i need to extend this to 30 and so on if i have more datacenters ?

Comment: `{0}` is just a reference to the first argument after `-f`, `{1}` is the second and so on. Since `$Country.DataCenter` always refers to the current datacenter in the `foreach` loop, you don't have to add any more placeholders to the string, no